# give an input field same properties as a div tag with css

Tags: html, css, input

i’ve a question about this code right underneath. So what it is, these are two input fields to give in a certain amount of hours and minutes. The red is with an input tag, the other (orange) is just a field with a class in a div. The problem: the input field has to take 70% of its height and if the sreen size schrinks the box has to stay inside the parent div. The orange box  (with just a div and class) does this properly, however the red input field always takes up a nearly invisible little more space. However how smaller the screen how bigger the diffrence is. How can I solve this or how to change te css so that the input field has the same behaviour as the div? thanks in advance!
[small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywb0J.jpg)

```css
/* bouwen van de rechoek met als er over wordt gegaan met de muis oplichten rand */

.vierkant{
  width: calc(100%/6*2);
 float:left;
 display: flex; 
 position: relative;
 
}

.vierkant-marges {
   flex: 1;
   border: solid 4px grey;
   border-radius: 10px;
   margin:5%;
   position: relative;
}

.vierkant-marges:hover {
   flex: 1;
   border: double 4px transparent;
   border-radius: 10px;
   background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #21d4fd, #b721ff);
   background-origin: border-box;
   background-clip: content-box, border-box;
   margin:5%;
}

.vierkant:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 50%;
 float:left;
}

/* content in het vak zal absoluut geplaatst worden en zal 100% innnemen */

.square-content{
    position:  absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0; 
}

/* creeren van het volledige deelblok ==> titel + invoervelden */

.volledigeInvoerBlok {
  /*background: green;*/
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100%/1);
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2vh;
  
}

/* creeren van het titelvak ==> neemt zoveel % in ==> absolute plaatsen titeltekst */

.actieveTijdTitel {
  /*background: blue;*/
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100%/3*1);
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2vh;
  float: left;
}

.actieveTijdTitel div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  color: grey;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-left: 1.25%;
  font-size: 1em;
}

/* creeren van het vak waarin de invoervakken komen */

.invoerTijd {
  /*background: orange;*/
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100%/3*2);
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2vh;
  float: left;
}

/* opmaak van de invoervelden */

.paddingTussenNz {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  /*background-color: yellow;*/
  position: relative;
}

.zichtbaareKaderBlauw {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  //padding: 15%;
 /* background-color: orange;*/
  position: relative;
}

.timeInput {
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
 width:100%;
  height: 70%;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:3vh; 
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  
}

.timeInput div {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  
}

::placeholder { 
  color: white;
}


.miniTextBox {
  /*background: blue;*/
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2vh;
}

.miniTextBox div {
  position: absolute;
  color: grey;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="vierkant" id="pauzeKader">
    <div class="vierkant-marges">
      <div class='square-content'>  
        
        <div class="volledigeInvoerBlok">
          <div class="actieveTijdTitel">  
            <div>
                gewenste speeltijd:
            </div>       
          </div>


          <div class="invoerTijd">  
               <div class="paddingTussenNz">
                 <div class="zichtbaareKaderBlauw">          
                   <input type="text" class="timeInput red" id="inputHours" name="uren" placeholder="00" maxlength="2"> 
                   <!-- <div class="timeInput"></div> -->
                   <div class="miniTextBox"><div>uren</div></div>
                 </div>
       </div>
               
       <div class="paddingTussenNz">
                 <div class="zichtbaareKaderBlauw">          
                   <!-- <input type="text" class="timeInput" id="inputHours" name="uren" placeholder="00" maxlength="2"> -->
                   <div class="timeInput orange"><div>00</div></div>
                   <div class="miniTextBox"><div>uren</div></div>
                 </div>
       </div>

             
          </div>
        </div>
        
        
        
        
        
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: grid might help you possible example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NWxRGwv

Comment: I was working on an example with grid aswell as the guy above me said. Also, as a fellow Belgian, try to keep your code in general (classNames, vars, ...) in english so other people can understand more what they stand for.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! this works very well, i considered a grid but thought that there was as way to fix this just without grid, with the div it works pretty well but looks to have other properties than using an input field therefore i thought there was a simpleler solution.

Comment: yess you're right, I will think about it next time posting a block of code!